# Validate multiple properties with one rule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, fluentvalidation, asp.net-mvc-validation

Person class

```
class person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}
```

Each property of this class must be validated with this rule

```
  RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty().Length(2, 50).WithMessage("*");
  RuleFor(x => x.FatherName).NotEmpty().Length(2, 50).WithMessage("*");
  RuleFor(x => x.FamilyName).NotEmpty().Length(2, 50).WithMessage("*");
```

I want to  group these properties in one rule that validate each property through these validation rules (NotEmpty, Length)

How to do this in fluent validation ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is just not repeating the steps, you can create array of whatever the lambda/Func/delegate type that fluent validations take, and lip over items in the array calling the same code with only the lambda expression replaced with the one from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have already solved your problem, but still. you can create extension class in fluent validation for your field

```
public class personValidator : AbstractValidator<person>
{
    public MyClassValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(person => person.FirstName).CheckName();
        RuleFor(person => person.FatherName).CheckName();
        RuleFor(person => person.FamilyName).CheckName();

    }
}
```

and the check itself

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string>
    CheckName<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
{
    return ruleBuilder.NotEmpty()
                      .Length(2, 50)
                      .WithMessage("*");
}
```